# Why does my Erlang server not sleep?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have written an Erlang OTP server that handles a single bullet in my game. When I start this process I want it to begin a recursive function with some delay in each request. My problem is that this delay does not seems to happen. I don't think that the handle info for 'forward' is requested at all... What am I doing wrong?

All the REPEATER strings is printed in the terminal once the server is started, without delay...

This is the call that is made from another server to start the bullet:

```
{ok,BullPid} = gen_server:start('bullet', [self(), Type, Direction, Pos, ClientMaster], []),
```

Here is the server:

```
-module('bullet').

-export([init/1, handle_info/2, handle_cast/2, terminate/2]).

repeater(0) ->
    exit(normal);
repeater(Counter) ->
    io:fwrite("REPEATER\n"),
    erlang:send_after(100, self(), forward),
    repeater(Counter-1).

init([Client, _Type, Direction, StartPos, ClientMaster]) ->
    gen_server:cast(self(), startRepeater),
    io:fwrite("BULLET INITED!!"),
    Size = {10, 10},
    {ok, {Direction, {StartPos, Size, Client}, ClientMaster}}.

handle_cast(startRepeater, {Direction, Bullet, ClientMaster}) ->
    repeater(200),
    {noreply, {Direction, Bullet, ClientMaster}}.

handle_info(forward, {Direction, {Pos, Size, Client}, ClientMaster}) ->
    io:fwrite("forward"),
    Hit = gen_server:call(ClientMaster, {bullet, {Pos, Size, Client}, Direction}),
    case Hit of
    {NewPos, object} ->
        io:fwrite("OBJECT"),
        gen_server:cast(Client, {updateBullet, {Direction, NewPos, self()}}),
        exit(normal);
    {NewPos, ID} ->
        io:fwrite("ID"),
        gen_server:cast(Client, {updateBullet, {Direction, NewPos, self()}}),
        ID ! {hit, Client},
        Client ! {frag, ID},
        exit(normal);
    {NewPos, move} ->
        io:fwrite("MOVE"),
        gen_server:cast(Client, {updateBullet, {Direction, NewPos, self()}})
    end,
    {noreply, {Direction, NewPos, ClientMaster}}.

terminate(_Reason, {_Direction, {_StartPos, _Size, Client}, _ClientMaster}) ->
    gen_server:cast(Client, {removeBullet, self()}),
    io:fwrite("bullet ~p terminated!\n", [self()]),
    ok.
```

Comment: Just a few notes: 1) Erlang is not the ideal choice for *most* game development (excluding, say, the server for an MMO); 2) if you insist on using Erlang, do not do things like representing a single bullet as a distinct process. You will hit a wall very, very quickly if you try to coordinate thousands of processes representing game objects by using timers. You're better off using a more traditional game loop, as it's easier to manage the timing from one point than a thousand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're starting your "repeater" is wrong. The way it's written, *every* repeater message will come to your processes mailbox after 100 milliseconds (plus whatever delay from calling repeater itself).

You can solve this simply by multiplying `Counter` by the timeout you're using. For instance:

```
repeater(0) ->
    ok; % don't exit here; exit after you *receive* the last forward message
repeater(Counter) ->
    io:fwrite("REPEATER\n"),
    erlang:send_after(100 * Counter, self(), forward),
    repeater(Counter-1).
```

Using this, you would receive `Counter` forward messages, each separated by *roughly* 100 milliseconds.